# “Unable to start service Intent” error when starting service from an Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

Here is the exact description of error-

```
Unable to start service Intent {cmp=com.example.firstapp/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

this is my android manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.firstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<service android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:isolatedProcess="false"
    android:label="iBeacon"
    android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService">
<meta-data android:name="background" android:value="true" />
    <intent-filter 
       android:priority="1" >
        <action android:name="com.example.firstapp.DID_RANGING" />
        <action android:name="com.example.firstapp.DID_MONITORING" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I am new to android and Java but I really have to make it working.
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: show the code to start service

Answer (score 0):

You did not register your service named `IBeaconIntentProcessor` and which package is...

```
com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon
```

Thats why it can't find the service.

You have register a service `IBeaconService` and which package is

```
com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service
```

Register your `Service` in the `Manifest.xml` as follows...

```
<service android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor">
```

Comment: How Can I register it in this file?

Comment: I updated your changes. Now same line is getting repeat-

"attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}"

Comment: without seeing your code its difficult to say anymore.

Comment: Its working...:)
the bluetooth device I was using has Bluetooth version 3.0. I needed 4.0
So I changed the device and now everything is working...
Thanks Hamid.